# What is this line of code?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Often in code I see a line of code, I have an idea it do something about event but not clearly know what it does.

Is it possible that I can attach form A's load event in Form B with this, or what is its benefit?

```
this.CGForm .Load +=new EventHandler(CGForm_Load);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it clearly has to do with events.

`.Load` in this case the the [`Form.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) event. The `+=` operator adds one event handler to the event. An event can have many event handlers at the same time. Event handlers are just regular method that can be anywhere in your code base. When the event fires all subscribed methods will be called, one after the other.

I see no particular good reason to have FormA listen to the `Load` event of FormB, but other events might be more interesting, like the [`Form.Closed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed.aspx) event. This is a way to have FormA react to changes in FormB.

**Edit**
Note that this causes FormA to hold a reference to FormB and FormB won't be garbage collected until FormA releases the reference to FormB (with
`this.CGForm .Load -=new EventHandler(CGForm_Load);`, note the `-=`) this is a common cause for memory leaks in .NET.

Subscribing to events from other forms is a "code smell" that can be a potential structure problem with your code. In some cases it is required, but if you have it all over the place your code will be hard to understand and maintain.

Comment: Thanks @Albin, please guide is it necessary to put -=new EventHandler() or after execution it is automatically garbage collective ?

Comment: kindly can you explain "Code Smell" ? in what cases event like this can be used and for what scenarios they should not be used ? thanks

Comment: [Code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) is something, a pattern or specific construct, in the code that could indicate quality or maintainability problems. In this case the "pattern" is that one form is depending on how the other works. If you have long chains of those dependencies you will often run into the situation where changes in one place in the code breaks functionality in a seemingly unrelated place.

Answer (score 3):

What this line means is that you subscribe the method `CGForm_Load()` to the `this.CGForm.Load` event. The method `CGForm_Load()` is the **event handler** or the **callback**.

After you run this line, every time the event is raised (in this case - every time the form is loaded), `CGForm_Load()` will be called automatically.

In order to *unsubscribe* a callback, use `-=` like this:

```
this.CGForm.Load -= new EventHandler(CGForm_Load)
```

Once an event callback is unsubscribed, the next time the event is raised (if the form is loaded again) the callback will no longer be called.

---

I find the following metaphor helpful: An event is like a power outlet, and callbacks are like power plugs. Subscribing is like connecting the plug to the outlet, and unsubscribing is like pulling it out. While there is a connection, all invocations of the event trigger the callback.

Answer (score 3):

It simply adds the GCForm_Load method to the Load event on the CGForm. Under the hood when the CGForm is loaded code like the following will execute. Whenever this happens all event subscribers (in this case the method being subscribed here as CGForm_Load) will be invoked.

```
<pseudocode>
class CGForm
{
  public EventHandler<FormLoadedEventArgs> Load;

  private void SomeMethodThatLoadsTheForm()
  {
    LoadForm();
    var loadHandlers = Load;
    if (loadHandlers != null)
    {
       loadHandlers(new FormLoadedEventArgs(...));
    }
  }
}
</pseudocode>
```

Answer (score 2):

`this.CGForm .Load +=new EventHandler(CGForm_Load);` subscribes the event handler delegate `CGForm_Load` to the `Load` event of the `CGForm` object.

Documentation about subscribing to events can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768(v=vs.80).aspx .

And index of information about how events work in .NET can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/awbftdfh(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: thanks, kindly advice me one thing. For getting message from a user control should I declared some custom delegate and get message or I can directly attach user control's button click even handler in my content page ?  thanks

Comment: @user576510, The convention is to set the `OnClientClick` attribute equal to the `EventHandler` in your code behind.  It doesn't need to be an `EventHandler` delegate - it can just be a method with the same signature as the `EventHandler` delegate, which is `void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)`.  A good tutorial on this is here: http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/events/ .  Some more advanced information on the Server Control Event Model can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3bwdsh3.aspx